Tappable Lable in particular string in Text in SwiftUI?
We need to move to new page when we tap on particualr text in String. As per SwiftUI
To achieve the desired behavior where only the "Pay Now" text is tappable, while keeping the visual appearance of a single sentence, we can simulate this interaction. Since SwiftUI doesn’t natively support partial tap detection within a Text or AttributedString, the best solution is to break the sentence into multiple Text views while ensuring that they are displayed seamlessly in a single line.
So I have decided to do with UIViewRepresentable and UILabel
Please see the text alignment issue. Please help me with this
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct TappableLabel: View {
    @State private var navigateToPayment = false // State to handle navigation

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    // Icon
                    Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .font(.system(size: 40))
                        .frame(width: 50) // Fixed width for the icon

                    // Attributed label view
                    AttributedLabelView(navigateToPayment: $navigateToPayment)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // Allow label to use full width
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) // Allow vertical growth

                    Spacer() // Push elements to the sides
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .shadow(radius: 5)
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
            .navigationTitle("Account Status")

            // Navigation to PaymentView when "Pay Now" is tapped
            NavigationLink(destination: PaymentView(), isActive: $navigateToPayment) {
                EmptyView() // Hidden NavigationLink
            }
        }
    }
}

// Wrapper for UILabel using UIViewRepresentable
struct AttributedLabelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var navigateToPayment: Bool // Bind state for navigation

    // Create the UILabel
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true // Allow user interaction
        label.numberOfLines = 0 // Allow multiple lines
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping // Ensure words wrap correctly
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear // Ensure background is clear
        label.textAlignment = .left // Set alignment explicitly

        // Create the attributed string
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your account is suspended. Pay Now")
        // Define the range for "Pay Now"
        let payNowRange = (attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: "Pay Now")

        // Add attributes to "Pay Now"
        attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: payNowRange)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: payNowRange)

        // Apply the attributed string to the UILabel
        label.attributedText = attributedString

        // Add tap gesture recognizer
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(context.coordinator.handleTap(_:)))
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        return label
    }

    // Update the view
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
        // No update logic needed in this case
    }

    // Coordinator for handling interactions
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    // Coordinator class to handle the interaction
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: AttributedLabelView

        init(_ parent: AttributedLabelView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        // Handle tap on the label
        @objc func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            guard let label = gesture.view as? UILabel else { return }
            let text = label.attributedText?.string ?? ""
            let range = (text as NSString).range(of: "Pay Now")

            // Check if the tap location is within the "Pay Now" range
            let location = gesture.location(in: label)
            let textBoundingBox = label.boundingRectForCharacterRange(range)
            if textBoundingBox.contains(location) {
                print("Trigger navigation to PaymentView when Pay Now is tapped")
                self.parent.navigateToPayment = true // Trigger navigation
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UILabel {
    func boundingRectForCharacterRange(_ range: NSRange) -> CGRect {
        guard let attributedText = self.attributedText else { return .zero }
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedText)
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()

        // Create a text container that matches the label's width
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0 // Remove padding

        // Add the text container to the layout manager
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)

        // Set the text storage to the layout manager
        layoutManager.textStorage = textStorage

        // Layout the text
        layoutManager.ensureLayout(for: textContainer)

        // Calculate bounding rect for the character range
        let boundingRect = layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: range, in: textContainer)

        // Convert to UILabel's coordinate system
        return boundingRect.offsetBy(dx: self.frame.origin.x, dy: self.frame.origin.y)
    }
}

struct PaymentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Payment View")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .navigationTitle("Payment")
    }
}

struct TappableLabel_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TappableLabel()
    }
}

It should navigate to next page only tap on Pay Now


Possible duplicate
